# Finding $(N,m)$ such that $3 \mid 2^Nm - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

Good evening everyone! Here is my "question". Find all pairs of natural numbers $(m,N)$ such that $3| 2^{N}m - 1$. Could I get some tips to get started. I've proven a few special cases using induction.

Comment: Could we get some context from you, John, on the few special cases of induction you've proven?  What pairs have you found?  Where are you stuck?  Please understand that this question needs more context.  It is very much lacking in that respect.

Comment: What were "special" about your special cases?  I'd simply try a few and see if there are some generalities and obvious patterns and see if you can grok a  reason why.  Also $2 = 3-1$ so $2^Nm-1 = (3-1)^N)m - 1$ so what does *that* tell you.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Hint: $\bmod 3\!:\ u:= 2^N\equiv (-1)^N\,$ so $\,u^2\equiv 1\,$ so $\,um\equiv 1\iff m\equiv u\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

We should start by noticing that:

$2^N = 
\begin{cases} 
1 \mod 3, & \text{if $N$ even}\\
-1 \mod 3, & \text{if $N$ odd}
\end{cases}$

Thus,
$ 2^N m = 
\begin{cases} 
m \mod 3, & \text{if $N$ even}\\
-m \mod 3, & \text{if $N$ odd}
\end{cases}$

and solving $2^Nm = 1 \mod 3$ we conclude that

$
\begin{cases} 
m = 1\mod 3, & \text{if $N$ even}\\
m = -1 \mod 3, & \text{if $N$ odd}
\end{cases}$

So all the pairs are $$\{(N,m): [(N = 0 \mod 2) \text{ and } (m = 1 \mod 3)] \text{ or }  [(N = 1 \mod 2) \text{ and } (m = -1 \mod 3)] \}$$

Answer (score 0):

HUGE HINT:  $2 = (3-1)$ so $2^Nm -1 = (3-1)^Nm -1$.